# Scikit - Combining scale and grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am new to scikit, and have 2 slight issues to combine a data scale and grid search.

1. Efficient scaler

Considering a cross validation using Kfolds, I would like that each time we train the model on the K-1 folds, the data scaler (using preprocessing.StandardScaler() for instance) is fit only on the K-1 folds and then apply to the remaining fold.

My impression is that the following code, will fit the scaler on the entire dataset, and therefore I would like to modify it to behave as described previsouly:

```
classifier = svm.SVC(C=1)    
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), classifier)
tuned_parameters = [{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]
my_grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, tuned_parameters, cv=5)
```

2. Retrieve inner scaler fitting

When refit=True, "after" the Grid Search, the model is refit (using the best estimator) on the entire  dataset, my understanding is that the pipeline will be used again, and therefore the scaler will be fit on the entire dataset. Ideally I would like to reuse that fit to scale my 'test' dataset. Is there a way to retrieve it directly from the GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. GridSearchCV knows nothing about the Pipeline object; it assumes that the provided estimator is atomic in the sense that it cannot choose only some particular stage (StandartScaler for example) and fit different stages on different data.
   All GridSearchCV does - calls fit(X, y) method on the provided estimator, where X,y - some splits of data. Thus it fits all stages on same splits.
2. Try this:

   `best_pipeline = my_grid_search.best_estimator_
   best_scaler = best_pipeline["standartscaler"]`
3. In case when you wrap your transformers/estimators into Pipeline - you have to add a prefix to a name of each parameter, e.g: `tuned_parameters = [{'svc__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]`, look at these examples for more details [Concatenating multiple feature extraction methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_feature_union.html), [Pipelining: chaining a PCA and a logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_digits_pipe.html)

Anyway read this, it may help you [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: So you are saying if I want to apply scaling based on train data I have to implement my own grid search? I think it's interesting that they don't provide functionality to apply preprocessing after train-test split. It's a common usage in order not to introduce bias to test data.

Comment: @brainoverflow98, I think you misunderstood the answer. The provided functionality does exactly what you demand.